# DesiredCapabilities for Selenium native android application obsolete

Tags: c#, android, selenium, appium-android

I am trying to set up a selenium framework to test a application on an android emulator. However I keep getting a warning that DesiredCapabilities is obsolete. I cant find any information on this apart from that relation to browsers. But in my framework I am trying to test a native application.

**Code:**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Open_Mobile_App()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        //set the emulator
        cap.SetCapability("platformVersion", "8.1");
        cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "Device 01 Oreo_1440x2560");
        cap.SetCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
        cap.SetCapability("deviceType", "phone");
        cap.SetCapability("device", "Android");
        cap.SetCapability("app", "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Mobile Tests/App APK/com.hyperspheric.go4schools.apk");
        cap.SetCapability("appPackage", "appPackage");
        cap.SetCapability("appActivity", "appActivity");


        _driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of DesiredCapabilites is obsoleted in latest selenium driver, we can use specific browser option for any browser and for android native app we can use AppiumOptions. Below code should work fine for android native app.

```
        AppiumOptions cap = new AppiumOptions();

        //set the emulator
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("platformVersion", "8.1");
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "Device 01 Oreo_1440x2560");
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceType", "phone");
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("device", "Android");
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Mobile Tests/App APK/com.hyperspheric.go4schools.apk");
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", "appPackage");
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("appActivity", "appActivity");
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET bindings are moving toward a pattern where DesiredCapabilites should not be
used directly. To facilitate that, the ChromeOptions class
has a ToCapabilities() method.

**EDIT:**

**This should work fine:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
DesiredCaps = options.ToCapabilities() as DesiredCapabilities;
DesiredCaps.SetCapability("platformName","Android");
DesiredCaps.SetCapability("platformVersion", "8.1");
DesiredCaps.SetCapability("deviceName", "Device 01 Oreo_1440x2560");
DesiredCaps.SetCapability("device", "Android");

AppDriver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), DesiredCaps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
```

Comment: I am just getting the error `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: You must include a platformName capability`

Comment: Check my updated answer. Use your capabilities according to your need. I have just shown how I have achieved this.

Comment: Sorry about my lack of understanding but using that code throws errors. `DesiredCaps`, `options`, and `AppDriver` all have errors such as `..does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the developpers of Appium ( who provide the `AnroidDriver` class ) haven't implemented a solution bypassing the use of the `DesiredCapabilities` class. ( I couldn't find any related issue or pull request )

As refered in this [selenium issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6284)