# How to use AndroidDriver or IOSDriver without DesiredCapabilities(which is deprecated)?

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, appium-ios, appium-android

AndroidDriver and IOSDriver require to have DesiredCapabilities as input.
Now, as this is deprecated how can I use these drivers?

My code example:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

cap.SetCapability("deviceName", ConfigReader("DeviceID"));
cap.SetCapability("udid", ConfigReader("DeviceID"));
cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
cap.SetCapability("systemPort", "SystemPort");
cap.SetCapability("language", ConfigReader("Language"));
cap.SetCapability("locale", ConfigReader("Language"));

IWebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri(uri), cap);
```

Can I get real example of alternative to this considering DesiredCapabilities deprecation?

There is also a similar topic for android still without proper answer [DesiredCapabilities for Selenium native android application obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728126/desiredcapabilities-for-selenium-native-android-application-obsolete/)

Answer (score 0):

We can create a session by using AddAdditionalCapability http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/create/

```
AppiumOptions capabilities = new AppiumOptions();
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "7.1.1");
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "Android Device");
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", "com.instagram.android");
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appActivity", "com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity");

AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), appiumOptions);
```